# url-encoding message content using get-url sms-service kannel

Tags: encoding, kannel

i using kannel for exchange messages to mobile operators with smpp link.
for MO messages i setup a kannel SMS-SERVICE and Set a get-url like below :

```
group = sms-service
keyword = default
get-url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/mo-messages/get?coding=%c&charset=%C&from=%p&to=%P&content=%a"
concatenation = true
forced-smsc = telecom
catch-all = true
max-messages = 0
```

when i send a "UCS2" message to my shortcode with mobile phone, kannel send a request to my get url with correct encoded text like this:

```
sent text in mobile : سلام@
and url requested by kannel : 
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/mo-messages/get?coding=0&charset=UTF-8&from=xxxx&to=xxxx&content=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%40
this is correct encoded @ in content : %40
```

but problem occurs when i send a "GSM ascci 7bit" message , @ in text did not properly url encoded. like below :

```
sent text in mobile : Hello@
and url requested by kannel : 
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/mo-messages/get?coding=0&charset=UTF-8&from=xxxx&to=xxxx&content=Hello%C2%A1 
this is incorrect url encoded @ in content : %C2%A1
```

i catch all Kannel URL requested with wireshark.
i cant convert this urlencoded string to @ with any charset.
kannel MO-RECODE feature doesn't affect to this , i tested with true and false MO-RECODE.

i tested it on Kannel 1.5.0 and Kannel 1.4.4 on Centos x64 6.7

i cant find any solution for this.

thankyou